# Xml vaildation fail

Tags: xml, dtd

I created a very simple xml file to store highscores, but validome.org says it isn't valid, and i can't figure out why.

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE HighScoreList [
<!ELEMENT HighScoreList (Highscore*)>
<!ELEMENT HighScore (Name, Score)>
<!ELEMENT Name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Score (#PCDATA)>
]>
<HighScoreList>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>1000</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>900</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>800</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>700</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>600</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>500</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>400</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>300</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>200</Score>
</HighScore>
<HighScore>
    <Name>Player</Name>
    <Score>100</Score>
</HighScore>
</HighScoreList>
```

And the error (at the last line):

Content of element type "HighScoreList" must match "(Highscore*)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different spellings, `Highscore` and `HighScore` (note the capital and lowercase `S`).